# Component template content appearing twice in angular2

Tags: angular

While my page is loading the component content is displaying twice.I tried with another component too, but i can't get the actual output.

Here is my app.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

    var routes : Routes = [
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: AppComponent
        },  
        { 
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'home'

         },

    ]

    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, AppComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    })
    export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

Comment: Don't define route for AppComponent seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

because you have this

```
var routes : Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: AppComponent
    },  
    { 
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'home'

     },

]
```

and this

```
template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1><router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
```

so when you navigate to `/` (root), it will redirect to `home`, and you will get 2 routes point to same component `AppComponent`

try to create `HomeComponent`, then `home` using `HomeComponent` not `AppComponent`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with LoginComponent liek below, But not working var routes : Routes = [{path: 'login',component: LoginComponent},{path: '',pathMatch: 'full',redirectTo: 'login'}]

Comment: you mean your app still print `Hello Angular` when you navigate to login

Comment: Yes. I am getting same.

Comment: ohh, let's me explain some concept: first your AppComponent is `root` component, when you using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, it's create a placeholder for any route, then content of Component defined by route (LoginComponent for example) will be put after this point. so in your AppComponent you have `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>` then when navigate to any route, the Component still alive, so you got `Hello Angular`. to remove this, just remove `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>` so your AppComp like this `template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',`

Comment: You are saying keep our `AppComponent` template only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

Comment: yeap, any data not belong to all children must be remove, then create new component to display it.

Comment: like this https://github.com/tieppt/angular-routing-example/blob/965c01c13572bc41aaa070dc7d1c1447c7e11d9a/src/app/product/product-routing.module.ts#L7-L23 and https://github.com/tieppt/angular-routing-example/blob/965c01c13572bc41aaa070dc7d1c1447c7e11d9a/src/app/product/product.component.html#L1

Comment: Ok. It's working fine. I tried like this `var routes : Routes = [{path: 'login',component: LoginComponent},{path: 'home',component: HomeComponent},{path: '',pathMatch: 'full',redirectTo: 'home'}]`

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139234/discussion-between-indepnt-dev-and-tiep-phan).